# Formik using React Native Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

My goal is to use a custom component based on `Switch` (from React Native) in a Formik form. Here is the code of the form component:

```
class NewPreferences extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.newPreferencesContainer}>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        food: true
                    }}
                    onSubmit={async (values, action) => {
                        await this.props.onSubmitPress(values)
                        action.setSubmitting(false)
                    }}
                    render={({
                        values,
                        errors,
                        touched,
                        handleChange,
                        handleBlur,
                        handleSubmit,
                        isSubmitting,
                    }) => (
                        <View style={styles.formikNewPreferences}>
                            <View style={styles.itemRow}>
                                <Field
                                    source={images.food.uri}
                                    onChange={handleChange('food')}
                                    value={values.food}
                                    name="food"
                                    component={ToggleButton}
                                />

                            </View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={styles.button}
                                onPress={handleSubmit}
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                            >
                                <Text>Login</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )}
                    />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The component `ToggleButton` is the following one:

```
class ToggleButton extends React.Component<ToggleButtonInterface> {
render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <Image
                source={this.props.source}
            />
            <Switch
                onValueChange={this.props.onChange}
                value={this.props.value}
                />
        </View>

    );
}
```

}

It appears that toggling the Switch element raises an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_a.type')`, in the method `_handleChange` of `Switch`. Following the documentation of Formik, I thought I simply needed to pass Formik's `handleChange` in the props of my custom component, so that when `Switch` is toggled, Formik changes its state, which will then change the props `value` of `Switch`.
Could anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Formik's `handleChange` expects to be called with a `React.ChangeEvent`.
Since the `onValueChange` of the `Switch` component will just be invoked with a boolean you need to use Formik's `setFieldValue` to handle the change.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ switch: false }}
  onSubmit={ values => console.log(values) }
>
  {props => (
      <Switch
        value={props.values.switch}
        onValueChange={value =>
          props.setFieldValue('switch', value)
        }
      />
  )}
</Formik>
```