# How change the value of a Switch in a Formik form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switch-statement, formik

do you know how to change the value of a Switch in a Formik form?

It's not working like other fields like Text Input or picker.

```js
<Picker onValueChange={handleChange('type')} selectedValue={values.type} style={{ height: hp('3%'), width: wp('30%') }} >...
 <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange('title')} onBlur={handleBlur('title')}...
```

I have tried many differents ways and followed a response in StackOverflow but my code does not know the "set Field Value" function

```js
 <Switch onValueChange={ value => setFieldValue('hidden', value)} value={values.hidden} style={{ marginTop: hp('-0.5%') }}></Switch>
```

[Formik using React Native Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422594/formik-using-react-native-switch)

This the initial values of thr form:

```js
initialValues={{
     title: '',
     type: 'Text',
     hidden: false,
     order: '0',
     graphicType: 'Camembert'
}}
```

Coudl you pleasse help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Check my custom component using useFormikContext, notice that the value is equal to *values[name]*

```
function SwitchInput({ name, icon, width = "100%", placeholder }) {
  const { setFieldValue, values, errors, touched } = useFormikContext();

  return (     
     <View>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={values[name] ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={(value) => setFieldValue(name, value)}
        value={values[name]}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
      </View>
  );
}
```